# Integration by parts (for distributional formulation)

Tags: integration, analysis

Consider $\gamma$ a regular curve, $k$ its curvature and $s$ the arclength parameter. Recall that $k=\partial^2_s\gamma$.  Consider the equation $$\begin{equation}\partial_t \gamma = k-2\partial^2_s k-k^3 \end{equation}$$ and take $\varphi$ a test function in $C_c^\infty$. I would like to obtain a distributional formulation of the above equation (I test with $\varphi$ and then I integrate by part). I should have
$$ \int\int\gamma (\partial_t\varphi-\partial^2_s \varphi+2\partial^4_s\varphi + [\dots]=0$$
I am not able to obtain $[\dots]$, i.e. the integration by part of $k^3\varphi$.